# set DeviceToken in parse for Android

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

i can't set the device token in Installation table using parse
im using

```
ParseInstallation installation =ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
      installation.put("GCMSenderId",senderId);
      installation.put("pushType","gcm");
      installation.put("deviceToken",token);
```

but when i try to use save i got an exception.

```
Cannot modify `deviceToken` property of an _Installation object. android
```

The problem is, the backend use this tokenId to send the push notification for another provider (OneSignal), so im wondering if its any way to write in the deviceToken row (As far as i know this is for iOS only).
i need write in the deviceToke the GCM token i receive.
Thanks

Comment: If you looking to migrate to OneSignal you only need to add `GCMSenderId` as the OneSignal parse importer will be able to bring in your existing users after you make this change.
https://onesignal.com/blog/important-note-for-android-parse-push-users/

Comment: If sdk not allow you, you can try rest api with currentUser token.

Comment: @jkasten It was able to bring my users but without the updated updating the deviceToken, I was not able to get pushes to successfully send.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by adding a Parse Cloud function called `setDeviceToken`. This way I can use the MasterKey to modify the Installation record.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("setDeviceToken", function(request, response) {
    var installationId = request.params.installationId;
    var deviceToken = request.params.deviceToken;

    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
    query.get(installationId, {useMasterKey: true}).then(function(installation) {
        console.log(installation);
        installation.set("deviceToken", deviceToken);
        installation.save(null, {useMasterKey: true}).then(function() {
            response.success(true);
        }, function(error) {
            response.error(error);
        })
    }, function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    })
});
```

Then, in my Android app's `Application.onCreate`:

```
OneSignal.idsAvailable(new OneSignal.IdsAvailableHandler() {
  @Override
  public void idsAvailable(String userId, String registrationId) {
      final ParseInstallation currentInstallation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();

      if (registrationId != null) {
          HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>(2);
          params.put("installationId", currentInstallation.getObjectId());
          params.put("deviceToken", registrationId);

          ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("setDeviceToken", params, new FunctionCallback<Boolean>() {
              @Override
              public void done(java.lang.Boolean success, ParseException e) {
                  if (e != null) {
                      // logException(e);
                  }
              }
          });
      }
  }
});
```

Comment: This is a useful workaround, I confirm is working on ParseServer v2.3.5 and Android SDK v1.14.1. If you are using Firebase  `String registrationId = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();` Just curious, why did you choose onesignal over Firebase @jaynp?

Comment: @JaimeAgudo OneSignal easily supports a bunch of advanced features like A/B testing, iOS 10 media attachments, actions buttons. I'm not using them all now, but it's nice to have that option!

Answer (score 0):

For future visitors, I solved this a different way, by using the Parse Rest API: http://parseplatform.org/docs/rest/guide/

Using that, you can bypass the regular SDK limitations. Just make a put request to https://yourApp/parse/installtions/{installationObjectIDHere}. make a dictionary and encode it as JSON:

```
    Map<String, String> dictionary = new HashMap<String, String>();
    dictionary.put("deviceToken", yourToken);
    JSONObject jsonDictionary = new JSONObject(dictionary);
    String bodyAsString = jsonDictionary.toString();
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, bodyAsString);
```

then send the request, and that should work.

Answer (score 0):

joey showed the right way to do that, the extra part i added is about the authentication header. 
This is what i did:

```
    val JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8")

    val client = OkHttpClient()

    val installationObjectId = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().objectId

    val myAppId = getString(R.string.parse_app_id)

    val key = getString(R.string.parse_client_key)

    val server = getString(R.string.parse_server_url)

    val mRequestUrl = "$server/installations/$installationObjectId"

    val dictionary = HashMap<String, String?>()
    dictionary["deviceToken"] = myToken
    val jsonDictionary = JSONObject(dictionary)
    val bodyAsString = jsonDictionary.toString()

    val body = RequestBody.create(JSON, bodyAsString)

    val request = Request.Builder()
            .url(mRequestUrl)
            .put(body)
            .addHeader("X-Parse-Application-Id", myAppId)
            .addHeader("X-Parse-Client-Key", key)
            .build()

    client.newCall(request).execute()
```